# L5.5 querybuilder where date not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

How can I check current time with availability_from and availability_ends date time,

I have tried with below code but it did not work

```
public function startSession()
{  
      $avialable = TimeSlot::where('mentor_provider_id',$menter_id)
                    ->where('available_from', '>=', Carbon::now())
                    ->where('available_ends', '<=', Carbon::now())
                    ->first();
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code??

Comment: Do you get an error or is `$available` just `null`?

Comment: yes it gives not available results even though available_from and available_ends is valid.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen yes it gives not available result even though available_from and available_ends is valid.

Comment: share what value stored in `available_from` and `available_ends` columns and what value you are getting in `Carbon::now()` ? **May be you are not considering local time and UTC**

Comment: @user2486 available_from = 2017-11-29 11:23:22 , available_ends = 2017-11-30 02:23:22 and Carbon::now() =2017-11-29 18:39:17

Comment: Romove this `where('mentor_provider_id',$menter_id)` and try, Also share value of `$menter_id` ?

Comment: @user2486 $menter_id values is 1 which is menter id

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereDate()` instead of `where()` :

```
public function startSession()
{  
      $avialable = TimeSlot::where('mentor_provider_id',$menter_id)
                    ->whereDate('available_from', '>=', Carbon::now())
                    ->whereDate('available_ends', '<=', Carbon::now())
                    ->first();
}
```

From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries):

> **whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear**
>
> The whereDate method may be used to compare a column's value against a date.

Comment: getting same result after using whereDate() instead of where()

Comment: I'm using DATETIME data type

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure that you are using operators the right way round?

*Try the following code:*

```
public function startSession()
{  
      $avialable = TimeSlot::where('mentor_provider_id',$menter_id)
                    ->where('available_from', '<=', Carbon::now())
                    ->where('available_ends', '>=', Carbon::now())
                    ->first();
}
```